# How to add both long-term and short-term interest rates as variables for a GARCH model?

Tags: data-transformation, garch, finance, unit-root, macroeconomics

I was facing some difficulties with a model of mine. I want to look up how the portfolio reacts to interest rate changes and I would like to use a GARCH model. However, both the short-term and long-term rates have unit roots and therefore I need to change them up I believe? I tried to dlog both of them, but since short-term interest rates from my period have been zero, EViews pops up an error. Is there a better way to deal with this, as I need to discuss the interest rate risk on a certain portfolio?

Answer (score 0):

Consider including changes in interest rates, i.e. simple differences without taking the logarithm first. Logarithms work well for variables (such as GDP) that grow exponentially over time. Interest rates do not do that, and thus are not usually modelled with logarithms.

Actually, even taking the first differences of interest rates is questionable, as discussed e.g. in Cochrane ["A Brief Parable of Over-Differencing"](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5e6033a4ea02d801f37e15bb/t/5eda716edf351879908c4cad/1591374191294/overdifferencing.pdf) (2018). But over short intervals of time the high level of persistence in interest rates may justify differencing.

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply! Do I take the simple difference (Interest at t MINUS interest at t-1) or I take the simple growth (interest/interest(-1))-1?

Comment: @VeryPleasant, take the simple difference: $\Delta x_t:=x_t-x_{t-1}$. The growth rates you propose are very similar to diff(log(.)), and the latter do not make much economic sense.

Comment: So in Eviews if I want to estimate the interest rate risk on my portfolio, I would put into the Garch estimator window dlog(portfolio) c dlog(market) deltatbill deltatbond ar(1)? Or is there something wrong with a model like this?

Comment: @VeryPleasant, it has been more than a decade since I used EViews last, and I have mostly forgotten the syntax. Could you write the model equation(s) mathematically instead?

Comment: Not sure how to correctly write this in a mathematical way but I'll try to write this as clear as I possibly can.
For the garch model my variables are:
First log difference on portfolio value (20years of data);
C as a constant, i.e. alpha;
First log difference on the S&P index prices;
Simple difference of Tbill rates (interest at time t MINUS interest at time t-1);
Simple difference of Tbond rates (interest at time t Minus interest at time t-1);

Comment: The problem I'm getting is that all of the portfolio is based on insurance companies, which are exposed to interest rate risk. However, whenever I run a regression like this, I get that both the changes in tbill and tbond rates are insignificant, therefore I believe I'm making a mistake somewhere or I'm using the model incorrectly

Comment: @VeryPleasant, I do not know enough about the subject matter to comment on that.

Comment: @VeryPleasant, what do you think about my answer? If it is helpful, consider accepting it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).